# How the activity of the browser tab affects the queries

Tags: javascript, axios, fetch-api

I develop excel parser. For any row in excel, I prepare a separate request (via Axios). I noticed that when browser tab with parser is not active (I'm on another tab), requests are slowly.

For requests, I use Axios and async loop. Any request wait for resolve previous request.

When a tab is active and I observe results, request execute one after the other (without delay), but when is inactive, between one and the other is a few second breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some browsers, definitely including Chrome, [aggressively throttle background tabs](https://thenextweb.com/apps/2017/01/26/chrome-throttle-background-tabs-google/) as a general performance feature.